# Nsight eclipse is pointing to wrong nvcc path in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, ubuntu-16.04, cuda

I have successfully installed nsight eclipse through cuda toolkit 10.1. I am able to compile sample cuda programs through command line but facing the error with nvcc path. Eclipse is pointing wrongly to nvcc path. Kindly help me.

[Error_nvcc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQj3M.png)

Comment: Do what is says in the error message and add it to your PATH

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Yes I have added in the path like below:


`export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/NsightCompute-2019.1${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}`

The actual path is  **/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin/nvcc** but eclipse is taking the path as **/usr/local/cuda-10.1/binnvcc**.